# Cannot inflate separator view into Radiogroup

Tags: android, kotlin

Assume a list of inflated views - `options = [RadioButton, RadioButton, View, RadioButton]` - where the View should be a separator line.

When i try todo this by inflating this into my radiogroup with following code snipped, the Radiobuttons are displayed in the RadioGroup but the View i want to have as a separator does not show up.

```
options.forEachIndexed { option_index, item ->
    radio_group.addView(item)
    if (option_index == indexToSelect) {
        radio_group.check(item.id)
    }
}
```

I checked with the debugger if the Radiogroup contains the View and this is the case. So i am a little bit confused why it does not show

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code. I tried simulating your situation with XML, putting a Button inside a RadioGroup and it shows up as expected.
Try adding a Button (which is usually bigger) in your RadioGroup, be sure to set is size with `LayoutParams` to `width=MATCH_PARENT` and `height=WRAP_CONTENT` and then call `addView(button)` to check if it appears

Comment: @MatPag did you also try with inflating those views?

Comment: @MatPag Somehow the same works if i Change View to a Button. Seems it just has Problems with a simple View

Comment: You have to be sure that the simple view has a visible height/width and a non-transparent background. I'm confident the problem is in your view and not in RadioGroup